# Ember restadapter specifying a host changes the http request method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I'm using the MVC.net 4 Ember Spa template and it works as it is, but when i change the adapter's host to something else like

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.WebAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api',
    antiForgeryTokenSelector: "#antiForgeryToken",
    host: 'http://whatever.com:3939/myapi'
});
```

the request method of the request is changed to OPTIONS for some reason.
WebAPi doesn't like this and doesn't do anything
Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

The `WebAPIAdapter` is really old, and unnecessary.  You can use the normal `RESTAdapter` to get the same effect.  It's also a little weird to name the namespace and the host, but to each his own.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'myapi',
  host:'http://whatever.com:3939',
  headers:{
    RequestVerificationToken:$('#antiForgeryToken').val()
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/511/edit

Comment: Thanks, I was just using exactly what was in the existing code from the template. The only reason for using the webAPIAdapter is to handle the situation of ember expecting named things like {person:{"firstname":"bob"}) but webapi returns only {"firstname":"bob"}. Is it best to just get webapi to return a different format instead of creatting a customer adapter?

Comment: My experience it is easier, especially if you have control of the endpoint.  Our .net app is supplying the data in the format Ember Data is expecting and it's worked out very well for us.